# What is the best way to embed external python modules to vim plugin?

Tags: plugin-system, vimscript-python

I decided to write a plugin for vim. I want to write it mainly in python, as I am most proficient in it. I started development with this example: http://brainacle.com/how-to-write-vim-plugins-with-python.html

But the problem I have - I want to use some non-standard library modules and I wonder - how should I add them? My guess is that vim uses it's own python that is compiled in it, therefore I cannot really use pip to install these modules. Should I just provide the modules I want to use within the plugin itself?

Comment: It would depend on the module. Is is widely packaged, or a more obscure module? Is it one file? Or a lot of files? Is the license compatible with your project's license?

Comment: >My guess is that vim uses it's own python that is compiled in it, therefore I cannot really use pip to install these modules.

Vim may use dynamic linked python more then one version. See `he: python-2-and-3`

Of course I can build vim myself with any version of python (py2 or py3) or with both of them.